# Eclipse and hierarchical file structure

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, hierarchical

I am using Eclipse 3.51 along with Maven 2.0.x, and Maven Eclipse plugin. The file structure of the project I am working on is hierarchical.

Based on several sources, including this link (http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/eclipse/faq.html#hierarchical although the url indicates it is Maven 1), Eclipse does not handle hierarchical file structure very well.

Does anyone have a workaround or guideline for me to get a hierarchical structure to work in Eclipse?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) can deal with [nested](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Importing+Maven+projects) projects. That seems to be a good workaround :)

Comment: I really like Maven Eclipse plugin because of its light weight and fast response. If I can't get it to work then I will go with m2.

Comment: @subferno I definitely agree with you but in that case, the recommended structure is a flat structure (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/multi-module-projects.html), with all the drawbacks.

Comment: Since Eclipse Mars, you can show the Project in a hierarchical structure in Project Explorer: https://www.eclipse.org/mars/noteworthy/#_nested_hierarchical_view_of_projects